# Is the _unit determinant_ constraint of a rotation matrix equivalent to handedness preservation constraint?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, rotations

For a matrix $R \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ to be a proper rotation $\in$ SO($3$), it has to satisfy two constraints:

- Orthonormality: $R^TR = RR^T = I$
- Orientation preservation: det($R$) = $1$

Some sources write orientation preservation constraint as if $R = [u_1, u_2, u_3]$, then orientation preservation: 
$$u_i \times u_j = u_k $$
, where $\times$ denotes the vector cross product and $(i,j,k) = \text{cycle}(1,2,3)$.

I am trying to preve that these two (the unit determinant and the crossproduct) constraints are equivalent for $3$-dimensional case, but no progress yet. Can anyone help me

Comment: Yes, this is true. A good way to prove it is by first showing that $\det R = (u_i\times u_j)\cdot u_k$.

Comment: Do you already know that orthonormality implies $u_i\times u_j = \pm u_k$?

Comment: @Arthur, Oh yeah. That's true. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the conditions $RR^T=I$ and $\det(R)=1$ are preserved under a cyclic permutation of the columns of $R$, we may assume without loss of generality that $(i,j,k)=(1,2,3)$. For convenience, let us drop the subscripts and write $R=[u,v,w]$. The cross product of $u$ and $v$ is *defined* as the unique vector $u\times v$ such that
$$
\det(u,v,r)=(u\times v)\cdot r\quad\forall r\in\mathbb R^3.
$$
It follows that
$$
R^T(u\times v)=\pmatrix{u^T\\ v^T\\ w^T}(u\times v)
=\pmatrix{(u\times v)\cdot u\\ (u\times v)\cdot v\\ (u\times v)\cdot w}
=\pmatrix{\det(u,v,u)\\ \det(u,v,v)\\ \det(u,v,w)}
=\pmatrix{0\\ 0\\ \det(R)}=\det(R)\pmatrix{0\\ 0\\ 1}
$$
and hence
$$
u\times v=RR^T(u\times v)=\det(R)R\pmatrix{0\\ 0\\ 1}=\det(R)w.\tag{1}
$$
As $R$ is non-singular, $w\ne0$. Therefore $(1)$ shows that $u\times v=w$ if and only if $\det(R)=1$.

Comment: So, det$(R) = 1$ is equivalent to $u \times v = w$ for any $R \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ matrix?

Comment: Under the assumption that $RR^T=I$, yes. In other cases, no in general.

Comment: Can you also include the proof of det$(u,v,w) = (u \times v) \cdot w$ for completeness?

Comment: @zeeshankhan There is no proof. It is **the definition** of cross product. Some high school or university-level engineering textbooks will call this the [scalar triple product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Scalar_triple_product), but in linear or multilinear algebra this is really the definition of cross product.